# Dynamically add a div and its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class='tagstore' id='tagstore'>
    <div class='tagsingle' title='delete'>323</div>
    <div class='tagsingle' title='delete'>525</div>
</div>
```

I need to add the following:

`<div class='tagsingle' title='delete'>some variable</div>`

**js**

```
var a = 'lorem';
var obj = "<div class='tagsingle' title='delete'>" + a + "</div>";
obj.appendTo('#tagstore');
```

Error:
`obj.appendTo is not a function...`

Also tried:

```
var obj = document.createElement('div');
obj.className = 'tagsingle';
obj.appendTo('#tagstore');
```

Error:
`obj.appendTo is not a function...`

Any help?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @KevinBoucher, of course, you can see from code

Comment: You are using a jQuery method on a vanilla JavaScript object (see my answer below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your main issue is that you are calling a JQuery method on a vanilla JavaScript object.**

There are many ways to accomplish what you are trying to do:

In JQuery, there is **[`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)**, but you have to call `.append()` on the object that the new element should be appended to, not the object that you are appending:

```js
var a = 'lorem';
var obj = "<div class='tagsingle' title='delete'>" + a + "</div>";
$("#tagstore").append(obj);

// Or, you can combine the creation of the string and the append:
$("#tagstore").append("<div class='tagsingle' title='delete'>" + a + "</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='tagstore' id='tagstore'>
    <div class='tagsingle' title='delete'>323</div>
    <div class='tagsingle' title='delete'>525</div>
</div>
```

And, there is also **[`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)**, but you have to call it on a JQuery object and pass a JQuery object as the object that you are appending to, not just a selector:

```js
var a = 'lorem';
var obj = "<div class='tagsingle' title='delete'>" + a + "</div>";
$(obj).appendTo($('#tagstore'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='tagstore' id='tagstore'>
    <div class='tagsingle' title='delete'>323</div>
    <div class='tagsingle' title='delete'>525</div>
</div>
```

To insert a string that contains some HTML, in vanilla JavaScript, it's **[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)**:

```js
var a = "Lorem";
document.getElementById("tagstore").innerHTML += "<div class='tagsingle' title='delete'>" + a + "</div>";
```

```html
<div class='tagstore' id='tagstore'>
    <div class='tagsingle' title='delete'>323</div>
    <div class='tagsingle' title='delete'>525</div>
</div>
```

But, `.innerHTML` requires building up the string and has security and performance issues. Using the DOM API, you **[create a new DOM node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)**, configure it and then use **[`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)** to add it to the document:

```js
var a = 'lorem';
var obj = document.createElement("div");
obj.classList.add('tagsingle');
obj.title='delete';
obj.textContent = a;
document.getElementById("tagstore").appendChild(obj);
```

```html
<div class='tagstore' id='tagstore'>
    <div class='tagsingle' title='delete'>323</div>
    <div class='tagsingle' title='delete'>525</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to create your object:

```
$('<div/>').addClass('tagsingle').appendTo('#tagstore');
```

`appendTo` is a jQuery method and you are trying to use it on a vanilla JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

`appendTo` is part of jQuery and `obj` needs to be a jQuery element. In your first example it's a string and in your second example it's a (simple vanilla js) Element.

If you want to use jQuery and create a jQuery element, just surround the string by `$("...")`.

```js
var a = 'lorem';
var obj = $("<div class='tagsingle' title='delete'>" + a + "</div>");
obj.appendTo('#tagstore');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='tagstore' id='tagstore'>
    <div class='tagsingle' title='delete'>323</div>
    <div class='tagsingle' title='delete'>525</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing jQuery and raw JS. The `.appendTo()` is a jQuery method and extends the `$()` Object - while in your case `obj` is actually a *String*.

Basic example from http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

> `$( "<p>Test</p>" ).appendTo( ".inner" );`

In jQuery you could use the Object Element constructor like:

```js
$("<div/>", {
  text: "lorem",
  "class": "tagsingle",
  title: "delete",
  appendTo: '#tagstore'
});
```

```html
<div class='tagstore' id='tagstore'>
    <div class='tagsingle' title='delete'>323</div>
    <div class='tagsingle' title='delete'>525</div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or if you like:

```
var text = "lorem";
var HTMLString = '<div class="tagsingle" title="delete">'+ text +'</div>';
$(HTMLString).appendTo('#tagstore') // Notice the wrapping $()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try `append('Content')` rather than `appendTo()`.

This should work fine.

Comment: The vanilla `.append()` method is not universally supported and the JQuery `.append()` needs to be called on a JQuery object to work.